# How does dpkg install a package?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

The dpkg manual states:

> This  manual is intended for users wishing to understand dpkg's command
>      line options and package states in more detail than  that  provided  by
>      dpkg --help.
>
> **It  should not be used by package maintainers wishing to understand how
>      dpkg will install their packages.** The descriptions of  what  dpkg  does
>      when installing and removing packages are particularly inadequate.

So where do I find the information on "how dpkg will install my packages"?

Answer (score 5):

You can read the various Debian documentation:

- [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html) - intended at new package maintainers like yourself. ([PDF here.](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/maint-guide.en.pdf))
- Debian FAQ:

  1. [Package management basics.](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)
  2. [Package management tools](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html).

Comment: Yes, i read those docs, but I haven't found the description of what exactly dpkg does step-by-step.

Comment: @v_2e You have read those docs completely? O.o

Comment: Of course, I dod not. I read through the sections mentioning dpkg in the two latter, and I read some sections in the former completely. Do you think these documents contain the kind of information I look for? I would be very grateful if someone helped me find it.

Comment: @v_2e The manpage itself gives the steps that `dpkg` takes when installing and configuring package (see the section for `--install`. To understand them better, you can look at these links.

Comment: Thanks for poining this out. Still I do not quite understand why the manual says "The descriptions of what dpkg does when installing and removing packages are particularly inadequate."

Comment: @v_2e I can only guess. I think that a package maintainer needs to understand that things are bit more complex, especially when it comes to the maintenance scripts, than the manual says. If you're not a package maintainer, the description would be enough.

Comment: Or, if you are into a horrendous data reduction problem, use `strace` or `ltrace`. These tools will let you trace the execution of `dpkg`. `man strace` and `man ltrace` to begin.

Comment: Btw. linked document I think is outdated now and there is the suggestion to use https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/index.en.html

Answer (score 3):

At a simple level, `dpkg` checks to see if dependencies/conflicts are met, extracts the files from the .deb file, runs any `{pre,post}{inst,rm}` scripts (whichever are applicable), and adds a record that the package is installed into its records (which is just a file, I think).

Comment: I think the record file is `/var/lib/dpkg/status`