# Sequence of the scripts that run when a debian package is installed

Tags: package-management, dpkg

When we run let's say

`dpkg -i some-package.deb`

What is the sequence of the scripts(tasks) that run for the installation to complete?

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/511353/740460), I understand that `prerm`, `preinst`, `postinst`, `postrm` are some of the scripts that get executed. I wanted to know what else is done other than this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens during a package upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94817/what-happens-during-a-package-upgrade)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Debian wiki page on [Maintainer Scripts](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) has flow charts describing all the possible cases. I won't copy all of them here, but here's one for example:

> [image: Upgrade of foo 1.2-3 (installed) to 1.2-4]

This seems to be most complex example, but in any case, this margin would be too narrow to contain a description of all the possible cases in words. ;)